# How to create custom legend with all options(click functions,colors) in ng2-charts in angular4?

Tags: angular, ionic3, ng2-charts

Iam working in angular4 and ionic3 project.Here Iam displaying ng2 pie charts for multiple data arrays.When data in a array is increasing,legend width is increasing and chat disappears due to large data.For this problem,I want to create a custom legend so that I can apply fixed width and scroll to the legend data that may not disappears the chart.How can I implement custom legend in angular2?
Here is my code:

```js
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private zone :NgZone, public navCtrl: NavController,
   public navParams: NavParams, public popoverCtrl:PopoverController, public modalCtrl: ModalController,
   public datepipe: DatePipe, private platform: Platform) {
    this.chartValues();    
    this.gmaildata=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gmaildata"));
      this.admin = db.list('/Admin');
      this.admin.subscribe(data => {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          if(this.gmaildata.email==data[i].email){
            this.admindisplay={
              email:data[i].email,
              startdate:data[i].startdate,
              enddate:data[i].enddate,
              name:data[i].name,
              remainingdays:Math.round(Math.abs((data[i].enddate-Date.now())/(1000*60*60*24)))
            }
          }
        }
      });
  }
    ngOnInit(){
    }

    /*this.getPatients();*/
    getData(x) {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(x);
        
      console.log(this.selectedItems);
      this.arr = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(this.arr.indexOf(x[i].id) < 0) {
        this.arr.push(x[i].id);
        }
      }
      console.log(this.arr);
      var ref = firebase.database().ref("Visits");
      this.hospInfoArr = [];
      var ref1 = firebase.database().ref("Expenses");
      this.expArr = [];
      var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("Patients");
      this.opArr =[];
      var ref3 = firebase.database().ref("Medicine");
      this.medArr = [];
    console.log("id",this.arr[i]);
          var id=this.arr[i];
        ref.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
          var x = dataSnapshot.val();
          var hosp=[];
          console.log(x);
            this.hospInfoArr.length = 0;
          for (var key in x) {
                  if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var element = x[key];
                      hosp.push(element)
                  }
                }
        console.log("hosp",(hosp),this.arr);
        for(var i=0;i<hosp.length;i++){
                 for(var j= 0; j < this.arr.length; j++) {
if(hosp[i].branchid == this.arr[j]){
            this.hospInfoArr.push(hosp[i]);
        }
                 }
        }
               console.log("hospInforArr",this.hospInfoArr);
             this.labels(this.hospInfoArr);
                
        });
        ref1.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (snapshot) => {
          var x = snapshot.val();
            this.expArr.length =0;
var expense=[];
          for(var key in x){
            if(x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              var ele = x[key];
              expense.push(ele);
            }
          }
            console.log("exp",expense);
            for(var i=0;i<expense.length;i++){
for(var j=0;j<this.arr.length;j++){
if(expense[i].branchid == this.arr[j]){
            this.expArr.push(expense[i]);
        }
    }
        }
          console.log("expenses",this.expArr);
          this.expenses(this.expArr);
        });
        ref2.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (snap) => {
          var x = snap.val();
            this.opArr.length = 0;
var ops=[];
          for (var key in x) {
            if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              var ele = x[key];
              ops.push(ele);
            }
          }
            console.log("opssss",ops);
                for(var i=0;i<ops.length;i++){
                 for(var j=0;j<this.arr.length;j++){   
if(ops[i].branchid == this.arr[j]){
            this.opArr.push(ops[i]);
        }
                 }
        }
          console.log("ops",this.opArr);
          this.ops(this.opArr);
          });
          ref3.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on('value', (snap1) => {
            var x = snap1.val();
              this.medArr.length = 0;
var medicine=[];
            for(var key in x) {
              if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var ele = x[key];
                medicine.push(ele);
              }
            }
              console.log("medi",medicine);
                       for(var i=0;i<medicine.length;i++){
for(var j=0;j<this.arr.length;j++){
if(medicine[i].branchid == this.arr[j]){
            this.medArr.push(medicine[i]);
        }
    }
        }
              console.log("medicines",JSON.stringify(this.medArr));
            this.medicine(this.medArr);
          });
          this.loading = false;
    }
labels(x){
    this.revenueSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
console.log(x);
this.pieChartLabels.length =0;
this.amountPaid.length = 0;
    this.pieChartData=[];
    this.barChartLabels1=[];
//this.data1 = [];
this.barChartData1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if(this.pieChartLabels.indexOf(x[i].branchname) < 0){ 
    this.pieChartLabels.push(x[i].branchname);
    this.barChartLabels1.push(x[i].branchname);
    }
    this.amountPaid.push({branch: x[i].branchname, amount: x[i].amountpaid});
    console.log("piechartlabels",this.pieChartLabels);
    console.log("amountpaid",this.amountPaid);
}
//console.log(this.pieChartLabels);
 
for(var i = 0; i < this.pieChartLabels.length; i++) {
this.sum = 0;
   for(var j = 0; j < this.amountPaid.length; ) {
     
    if(this.pieChartLabels[i] == this.amountPaid[j].branch) {
        this.sum = Number(this.sum) + Number(this.amountPaid[j].amount);
    console.log("sum",this.sum);
      j++;
    } else {
      j++;
    }
   }
   console.log(this.sum);
   this.pieChartData.push(this.sum);   
   this.data1.push(this.sum);
  
 }
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData.length;i++){
    this.revenueSum=this.revenueSum+Number(this.pieChartData[i]);
}       
 if(this.pieChartLabels.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels1.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels2.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels3.length==0){
            this.hideMsg=false;
        }
 console.log(this.pieChartData);
 this.barChartData1.push({data: this.data1});
}
expenses(y) {
    console.log("visits",y);
    this.expenseSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
  console.log(y);
  this.pieChartLabels1.length=0;
  this.money = [];
  this.pieChartData1 = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    if(this.pieChartLabels1.indexOf(y[i].branchname) < 0){
      this.pieChartLabels1.push(y[i].branchname);
    }
    console.log("expenses labels",this.pieChartLabels1);
    this.money.push({branch: y[i].branchname, amount: y[i].amount});
  }
  console.log(this.pieChartLabels1);
  console.log(this.money);
  for(var i = 0; i < this.pieChartLabels1.length; i++) {
    this.sum = 0;
   
     for(var j = 0; j < this.money.length;j++ ) {
       
      if(this.pieChartLabels1[i] == this.money[j].branch) {
        
          this.sum = Number(this.sum) + Number(this.money[j].amount);
      } 
     }
     console.log(this.sum);
     this.pieChartData1.push(this.sum);
     
   }
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData1.length;i++){
    this.expenseSum=Number(this.expenseSum)+Number(this.pieChartData1[i]);
}
   if(this.pieChartLabels.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels1.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels2.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels3.length==0){
            this.hideMsg=false;
        }
   console.log(this.pieChartData1);
   this.loading = false;
}
ops(x) {
    console.log("ops",x);
    this.opSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
    console.log("labels of op",x)
  this.pieChartLabels3.length=0;
  this.op = [];
  this.pieChartData3 = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if(this.pieChartLabels3.indexOf(x[i].branchname) < 0){
      this.pieChartLabels3.push(x[i].branchname);
    }
    //console.log("ops labels",this.pieChartLabels3);
    this.op.push({branch: x[i].branchname, op: x[i].op});
  }
    console.log("ops",this.op,this.pieChartLabels3);
  for(var i = 0; i < this.pieChartLabels3.length; i++){
    this.count = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < this.op.length; j++) {
      if(this.pieChartLabels3[i] == this.op[j].branch) {
        this.count++;
      }
    }
    this.pieChartData3.push(this.count);
  }
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData3.length;i++){
    this.opSum=this.opSum+Number(this.pieChartData3[i]);
}
    if(this.pieChartLabels.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels1.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels2.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels3.length==0){
            this.hideMsg=false;
        }
  this.loading = false;
}
medicine(x) {
    console.log("medicine",x);
    this.medicineSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
  this.pieChartLabels2.length=0;
  this.amount = [];
    this.pieChartData2=[];
    this.barChartLabels=[];
  this.data = [];
  this.barChartData = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(this.pieChartLabels2.indexOf(x[i].branchname) < 0){ 
      this.pieChartLabels2.push(x[i].branchname);
      this.barChartLabels.push(x[i].branchname);
      }
      this.amount.push({branch: x[i].branchname, amount: x[i].amount});
  }
  console.log(this.pieChartLabels2);
  console.log(this.amount);
  //console.log(this.barChartLabels);
  for(var i = 0; i < this.pieChartLabels2.length; i++) {
    this.sum = 0;
     for(var j = 0; j < this.amount.length;j++) {      
      if(this.pieChartLabels2[i] == this.amount[j].branch) {
    console.log("branches",this.pieChartLabels2[i],this.amount[j].branch)
          this.sum = Number(this.sum) + Number(this.amount[j].amount);
      } 
     }
     console.log(this.sum);
     this.pieChartData2.push(this.sum);   
     this.data.push(this.sum);
    
   }
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData2.length;i++){
    this.medicineSum=this.medicineSum+Number(this.pieChartData2[i]);
}
    if(this.pieChartLabels.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels1.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels2.length==0&&this.pieChartLabels3.length==0){
            this.hideMsg=false;
        }
   console.log(this.pieChartData2,this.pieChartLabels2);
   this.barChartData.push({data: this.data});
   console.log(this.barChartData);
   this.loading = false;
}  
  chartValues(){
    this.loading = true;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("Visits");
      this.Revenue.length = 0;
    ref.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      var x = snap.val();
      for (var key in x) {
        if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var element = x[key];
          this.Revenue.push(element);
        }
      }
    console.log("revenue",this.Revenue)
      this.labels(this.Revenue);
    });
      var ref1 = firebase.database().ref("Expenses");  
this.Expenses.length = 0;
ref1.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (snap) => {
        console.log(snap.val());
        var x = snap.val();
        for (var key in x) {
          if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var element = x[key];
            this.Expenses.push(element);
          }
        }
    console.log("expenses",this.Expenses)
        this.expenses(this.Expenses);
      });
      var ref = firebase.database().ref("Medicine");
      this.Medicine.length = 0;
      ref.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (snap) => {
        console.log(snap.val());
        var x = snap.val();
        for (var key in x) {
          if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var element = x[key];
            this.Medicine.push(element);
          }
        }
           console.log("medicine",this.Medicine)
        this.medicine(this.Medicine);
      });
    var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("Patients");
      this.Patient.length = 0;
    ref2.orderByChild("adminid").equalTo(this.ld).on("value", (snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      var x = snap.val();
      for (var key in x) {
        if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var element = x[key];
          this.Patient.push(element);
        }
      }
        console.log("ops",this.Patient)
      this.ops(this.Patient);
    });
    this.loading = false;
  }
  chartClicked(event) {
    console.log(event);
      
if(event.active.length > 0){
  var points = [];
  var pointSelected = event.active[0]._chart.tooltip._model.caretY;
  var legends = event.active[0]._chart.legend.legendItems;

  for (var i = 0; i < event.active.length; ++i) {
    points.push(event.active[i]._model.y);
  }

  let position = points.indexOf(pointSelected);
  let label = legends[position].text

  console.log("Point: "+label)
}
  }
rangeSelected(range,patients){
    this.opSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
    console.log("range",range);
    this.count1 = 0;
    this.pieChartData3 = [];
    this.pieChartLabels3.length = 0;
var branchArr =[];
var opamounts = [];
    console.log("pats",JSON.stringify(patients))
for(var i= 0;i<patients.length;i++){
var dateVal:any;
    dateVal=new Date(patients[i]['date']);
    dateVal=this.datepipe.transform(dateVal, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log("patientdate",(dateVal),typeof(range[0]),range[0]<=dateVal);
if(range[0]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[1]){
if(this.pieChartLabels3.indexOf(patients[i].branchname) < 0){
   branchArr.push(patients[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels3.push(patients[i].branchname);
}
opamounts.push({branch:patients[i].branchname,amount:patients[i].op})     
}
    else if(range[1]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[0]){
if(this.pieChartLabels3.indexOf(patients[i].branchname) < 0){
    branchArr.push(patients[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels3.push(patients[i].branchname);
}
opamounts.push({branch:patients[i].branchname,amount:patients[i].op})     
}  
   } 
for(var i =0;i<branchArr.length;i++){
    console.log("bracnharr length",branchArr);
    var count =0;
for(var j=0;j<opamounts.length;j++){
if(branchArr[i] == opamounts[j].branch){
    count++;
}
}
    this.pieChartData3.push(count);    
}
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData3.length;i++){
    this.opSum=Number(this.opSum)+Number(this.pieChartData3[i]);
}
    console.log("ops date",this.pieChartLabels3);
//this.loading = false;
}
    /*expenses selected for the admin*/
expSelected(range,adminExp){
    this.expenseSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
      this.count1 = 0;
    this.pieChartData1= [];
    this.pieChartLabels1.length = 0;
var branchArr =[];
var amounts = [];
    var sum=0;
    console.log("pats",JSON.stringify(this.adminExp))
for(var i= 0;i<adminExp.length;i++){
var dateVal:any;
    dateVal=new Date(adminExp[i]['date']);
    dateVal=this.datepipe.transform(dateVal, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log("patientdate",(dateVal),typeof(range[0]),range[0]<=dateVal);
if(range[0]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[1]){
if(this.pieChartLabels1.indexOf(adminExp[i].branchname) < 0){
   branchArr.push(adminExp[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels1.push(adminExp[i].branchname);
}
amounts.push({branch:adminExp[i].branchname,amount:adminExp[i].amount})     
}
    else if(range[1]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[0]){
if(this.pieChartLabels1.indexOf(adminExp[i].branchname) < 0){
    branchArr.push(adminExp[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels1.push(adminExp[i].branchname);
}
amounts.push({branch:adminExp[i].branchname,amount:adminExp[i].amount})     
}  
   } 
for(var i =0;i<branchArr.length;i++){
    console.log("bracnharr length",branchArr.length,amounts);
    var count =0;
    sum=0
for(var j=0;j<amounts.length;j++){
if(branchArr[i] == amounts[j].branch){
    sum=Number(sum)+Number(amounts[j].amount);
}
}
    this.pieChartData1.push(sum);    
}  
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData1.length;i++){
    this.expenseSum=Number(this.expenseSum)+Number(this.pieChartData1[i]);
}
    console.log("expense date",this.pieChartLabels1);
//this.loading = false; 
}
visitSelected(range,adminVisits){
    this.revenueSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
        this.count1 = 0;
    this.pieChartData=[];
    this.pieChartLabels.length = 0;
var branchArr =[];
var amounts = [];
    var sum=0;
    console.log("pats",JSON.stringify(this.adminExp))
for(var i= 0;i<adminVisits.length;i++){
var dateVal:any;
    dateVal=new Date(adminVisits[i]['date']);
    dateVal=this.datepipe.transform(dateVal, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log("patientdate",(dateVal),typeof(range[0]),range[0]<=dateVal);
if(range[0]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[1]){
if(this.pieChartLabels.indexOf(adminVisits[i].branchname) < 0){
   branchArr.push(adminVisits[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels.push(adminVisits[i].branchname);
}
amounts.push({branch:adminVisits[i].branchname,amount:adminVisits[i].amountpaid})     
}
    else if(range[1]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[0]){
if(this.pieChartLabels.indexOf(adminVisits[i].branchname) < 0){
    branchArr.push(adminVisits[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels.push(adminVisits[i].branchname);
}
amounts.push({branch:adminVisits[i].branchname,amount:adminVisits[i].amountpaid})     
}  
   } 
for(var i =0;i<branchArr.length;i++){
    console.log("bracnharr length",branchArr.length,amounts);
    var count =0;
    sum=0
for(var j=0;j<amounts.length;j++){
if(branchArr[i] == amounts[j].branch){
    sum=Number(sum)+Number(amounts[j].amount);
}
}
    this.pieChartData.push(sum);    
} 
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData.length;i++){
    this.revenueSum=Number(this.revenueSum)+Number(this.pieChartData[i]);
}
    console.log("visit date",this.pieChartLabels);
this.loading = false;
}
medSelected(range,medicine){
    this.medicineSum=0;
  this.loading = true;
    this.pieChartData2=[];
    this.pieChartLabels2.length = 0;
var branchArr =[];
var amounts = [];
    var sum=0;
    console.log("pats",JSON.stringify(medicine))
for(var i= 0;i<medicine.length;i++){
var dateVal:any;
    dateVal=new Date(medicine[i]['date']);
    dateVal=this.datepipe.transform(dateVal, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log("patientdate",(dateVal),typeof(range[0]),range[0]<=dateVal&&dateVal<=range[1]);
if(range[0]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[1]){
if(this.pieChartLabels2.indexOf(medicine[i].branchname) < 0){
   branchArr.push(medicine[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels2.push(medicine[i].branchname);
}
amounts.push({branch:medicine[i].branchname,amount:medicine[i].amount})     
}
    else if(range[1]<=dateVal && dateVal<=range[0]){
if(this.pieChartLabels2.indexOf(medicine[i].branchname) < 0){
    branchArr.push(medicine[i].branchname); 
    this.pieChartLabels2.push(medicine[i].branchname);
}
amounts.push({branch:medicine[i].branchname,amount:medicine[i].amount})     
}  
   } 
for(var i =0;i<branchArr.length;i++){
    console.log("bracnharr length",branchArr,amounts);
    var count =0;
    sum=0
for(var j=0;j<amounts.length;j++){
if(branchArr[i] == amounts[j].branch){
    sum=Number(sum)+Number(amounts[j].amount);
}
}
    this.pieChartData2.push(sum);    
} 
//this.loading = false;
for(var i=0;i<this.pieChartData2.length;i++){
    this.medicineSum=Number(this.medicineSum)+Number(this.pieChartData2[i]);
}
    console.log("medicine date",this.pieChartLabels2);
}

    //.............................
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    if (this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
      this.hideprofile = true;
    } 
  }

 
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 *ngIf="pieChartLabels.length> 0">
                <ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white;">
                    <ion-card-header style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">REVENUE
                            <span style="float:right;">{{revenueSum}}</span></p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData1" [labels]="pieChartLabels1" [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                    </ion-card-content>

                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 *ngIf="pieChartLabels1.length > 0">
                <ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white">
                    <ion-card-header style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">EXPENSES
                            <span style="float:right;">{{expenseSum}}</span></p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <ion-grid>
                            <ion-row>
                                <ion-col col-md-8>
                                    <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData1" [labels]="pieChartLabels1" [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)" [legend]="false"></canvas></ion-col>
                                <ion-col col-md-4 *ngIf="pieChartLabels1" style="height: 130px;overflow: auto">
                                    <ul baseChart>
                                        <li *ngFor="let data of pieChartLabels1"><span (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">{{data}}</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ion-col>
                            </ion-row>
                        </ion-grid>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 *ngIf="pieChartLabels2.length > 0">
                <ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white">
                    <ion-card-header style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">MEDICINES
                            <span style="float:right;">{{medicineSum}}</span></p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData2" [labels]="pieChartLabels2" [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 *ngIf="pieChartLabels3.length > 0">
                <ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white">
                    <ion-card-header style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">OP'S
                            <span style="float:right;">{{opSum}}</span></p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData3" [labels]="pieChartLabels3" [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                    </ion-card-content>

                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 *ngIf="pieChartLabels.length > 0">
                <ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white">
                    <ion-card-header padding style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">REVENUE</p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData1" [labels]="barChartLabels1" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 *ngIf="pieChartLabels2.length > 0">
                <ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white">
                    <ion-card-header padding style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">MEDICINES</p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```